# Generate unigrams from google books that start with a number, using regex

Tags: python, regex, nltk, n-gram

The code below, generates pickle dictionaries of unigrams of google books.
It generates 26 dictionaries like dictionary of words starting with a, b, c, ..., z.

```
p = re.compile(r'^[a-z]*$', re.IGNORECASE)
el = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

for l in el:
    fname, url, records = next(readline_google_store(ngram_len=1, indices=l))
    unigrams = {}
    count = 0
    for r in records:
        if (r.year >=2000):
            w = r.ngram.lower()
            if p.match(w):
                if w in unigrams:
                    unigrams[w] += np.array([r.match_count, r.volume_count])
                else:
                    unigrams[w] = np.array([r.match_count, r.volume_count])
    with open(str(l)+'_unigram_dict.pickle', 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(unigrams, f)
```

The output is like `{'word':[total_match_count, total_volume_count]}`

I want to change it to have only dictionary of words that start with a number.
The regex should catch a pattern that start with a number (from 0 to 9) followed by any character. 
I tried `re.compile(r'^(?:\d*\.)?\d+$', re.IGNORECASE)` but it only catches numeric words. It does not capture words like:
"00161_VERB" or "002,200_NUM" or "01-73", etc

Edit: input is (a record) in this format:

```
ngram TAB year TAB match_count TAB page_count NEWLINE
```

I want the output to be a dictionary with key ngrams that start with '0' and 
value a list ['sum of match_count over the years', 'sum of page_count over the years'] like this:

```
{'ngrams':['sum of match_count over the years', 'sum of page_count over the years']}
```

Comment: Give sample inputs and desired outputs that includes the outliers that you can't catch. That'll help us to answer the question better =)

Comment: Try just `re.compile(r'^\d')`.

Comment: ```re.compile(r'^\d')``` does not capture ngrams like '002,200_NUM'

Comment: I just added sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved,
`re.compile(r'^\d\S+')` worked.